# How to get a mouse event to fire on element obscured by another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have one element that is out of position in terms of the normal css flow (it has absolute position). This means that it obscures areas of other elements.

**What I want is for the element *positionally* below to receive mouse events when they occur on the obscuring element.**

NB: I do not want to use the css `pointer-events: none` because I still need to see mouse events on the obscuring object.

See example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7ZpAp/6/

I want the "three" element to receive the mouse event.

---

**Additional Info/Motivation:** I'm trying to implement drag/drop functionality with Jquery UI. The "two" element is dragged from "one" to a "three" type element.

The dropping of an element (element "two" in example) should occur over the obscured element ("three"). There may be more than one element "two" can be dropped in - I want the event to detect which element it has been dropped in.

The `mouseup` event is the one I'm detecting, and the handler is attached to element "three". There currently appears to be a change in behaviour when "three" appears before "one" in the dom, as opposed to after! I have no idea why this would happen.

Comment: As long as you're using jQuery-UI, why not use [`Droppable`](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)?

Comment: I didn't know it existed! Should have turned myself off, and then on again.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting position: relative on the "three" element.